# SolidWorks API (VBA) To store String in array

Tags: vba, api, solidworks

I want to store the dimension name (string) in the form of the array so that I can compare another array (dimension name) to the current.

```
Public Sub WhateverName

    Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel As ModelDoc2
    Dim swPart As PartDoc
    Dim swFeat As Feature
    Dim swDispDim As DisplayDimension
    Dim swDim As Dimension
    Dim vDimVals As Variant
    Dim swDimInfoNameArr As Variant
    Dim SKETCH_NAME As String
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim swDimName As Variant
    Dim swDispDimname As String
    
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swPart = swModel
    SKETCH_NAME = "ISO Standard"
    Set swFeat = swPart.FeatureByName(SKETCH_NAME)
    Set swDispDim = swFeat.GetFirstDisplayDimension
        
        Do While Not swDispDim Is Nothing
            i = 0
            'For i = 0 To 4
            Set swDim = swDispDim.GetDimension2(Empty)
            vDimVals = swDim.GetValue3(swThisConfiguration, Empty)
           
            Debug.Print swDim.Name & "@" & SKETCH_NAME & ": " & Round(vDimVals(0), 6)
            Set swDispDim = swFeat.GetNextDisplayDimension(swDispDim)
            swDimName = swDim.Name
            swDimInfoNameArr(i) = swDimName 'swModel.GetCustomInfoNames2     --> ERROR
            i = i + 1
            'Next
        Loop

End Sub
```

27th line is throwing the error "Type Mismatch"

Comment: You need to either declare the size of  'swDimInfoName' at first declaration or use a redim statement to set an appropriate size before you can use it as an array, otherwise its just a standard variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the size of the array, or use an other object to store. Like a dictionnary:

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()

Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel As ModelDoc2
Dim swPart As PartDoc
Dim swFeat As Feature
Dim swDispDim As DisplayDimension
Dim swDim As Dimension
Dim vDimVals As Variant
Dim SKETCH_NAME As String
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
Set swPart = swModel
SKETCH_NAME = "ISO Standard"
Set swFeat = swPart.FeatureByName(SKETCH_NAME)
Set swDispDim = swFeat.GetFirstDisplayDimension
 
    Do While Not swDispDim Is Nothing
        Set swDim = swDispDim.GetDimension2(Empty)
        vDimVals = swDim.GetValue3(swThisConfiguration, Empty)
        Set swDispDim = swFeat.GetNextDisplayDimension(swDispDim)
        dict.Add swDim.Name, Round(vDimVals(0), 6)
        
        Debug.Print dict.keys()(dict.Count - 1) & "@" & SKETCH_NAME & ": " & dict.Items()(dict.Count - 1)
    Loop
End Sub
```